# Is Batman Beyond the Farthest Future DC Timeline Established?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, dc-animated-universe, batman-beyond

In Batman Beyond, as many know, we are introduced to Terry McGinnis, who dons the cowl and takes over as the Dark Knight many decades into the future.

Is the Batman Beyond series the furthest serialized future timeline point in the DC universe we’ve ever seen established in comics/films/series?

This does not count one-off timeline jumps due to other stories involving other heroes in other series. I’m referring to full-on serialized for the long-term.

Answer (score 27):

#### No.

The [Legion of Super-Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Super-Heroes) are a team of superheroes who live in the 30th and 31st centuries. They have had a significant run of their own, and date back to comics about a young version of Superman regularly traveling forward in time to have adventures with them.

Additionally, [DC One Million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_One_Million) was a 1998 crossover event set in the 853rd century, and included 4 standard-length comics, 34 crossover comics, and an 80-page one-shot issue.

Comment: Justice League 3,000, Future’s End, Final Crisis, Superman/Batman: Generations, Superman Beyond

Comment: 853rd century...  Sounds like a big, random number pulled out of a hat, to wow 5-year-olds.  Sounds like something really difficult to maintain a well-developed, sensible story line with.  Sounds like...something *Marvel* would do.

Comment: @Panzercrisis not random. "853rd century (85,201–85,300 AD), chosen because that is the century in which DC Comics would have published issue #1,000,000 of their comics if they had maintained a regular publishing schedule." And DC has their share of undeveloped, nonsensical stories.